# Displaying a list of fields in a form select

Tags: plugin-development, field

In a plugin's settings view, I'm looking to show a list of fields to choose from:

```
{% set fields = craft.fields.getAllFields() %}  

{{ forms.selectField({
    label:          'Salary Mapping'|t,
    id:             'broadbeanSalaryMapping',
    name:           'broadbeanSalaryMapping',
    instructions:   'Choose a field in which to store this value.'|t,
    value:          settings.broadbeanSalaryMapping,
    options:        fields,
    errors:         settings.getErrors('broadbeanSalaryMapping')
}) }}
```

However I get an error:

> Craft\FieldModel and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "optgroup".

Am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 4):

I've got a solution, though I'd be interested to know if there is a better way of doing it. In the plugin file:

```
public function getSettingsHtml()
{
    $options = [[
        'label' => 'Please select', 
        'value' => ''
    ]];

    foreach (craft()->fields->getAllFields() as $field)
    {
        $options[] = [
            'label' => $field['name'], 
            'value' => $field['handle']
        ];
    }

    return craft()->templates->render('broadbean/settings', array(
        'settings' => $this->getSettings(), 
        'options' => $options
    ));
}
```

And then in the settings template:

```
{{ forms.selectField({
    label:          'Salary Mapping'|t,
    id:             'broadbeanSalaryMapping',
    name:           'broadbeanSalaryMapping',
    instructions:   'Choose a field in which to store this value.'|t,
    value:          settings.broadbeanSalaryMapping,
    options:        options,
    errors:         settings.getErrors('broadbeanSalaryMapping')
}) }}
```