# Model and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "optgroup"

Tags: plugin-development, plugins, fieldtypes, custom-fieldtype

I'm attempting to finish my first `fieldtype` plugin (how exciting!) but having an issue with displaying options in a `select` dropdown in an `entry`.

My `ColumnWidth_WidthsFieldType` has this:

```
<?php

namespace Craft;

/**
 * Widths Fieldtype
 *
 * Allows entries to select associated widths
 */
class ColumnWidth_WidthsFieldType extends BaseFieldType
{
    /**
     * Get the name of this fieldtype
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return Craft::t('Column Widths');
    }

    /**
     * Get this fieldtype's column type.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function defineContentAttribute()
    {
        // "Mixed" represents a "text" column type, which can be used to store arrays etc.
        return AttributeType::Mixed;
    }

    /**
     * Get this fieldtype's form HTML
     *
     * @param  string $name
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return string
     */
    public function getInputHtml($name, $value)
    {
        // call our service layer to get a current list of widths
        $widths = craft()->columnWidth_widths->getAllWidths();

        // create an array for the widths 
        $widthsOptions = array();

        // populate the $widthsOptions array with $widths
        foreach ($widthsOptions as $widths )
        {
            $widthsOptions[$widths->id] =  $widths->name;
        }

        return craft()->templates->render('columnwidth/_fieldtypes/widths', array(
            'name'      => $name,
            'values'    => $value,
        ));
    }
}
```

My `columnwidth/_fieldtypes/widths` has this:

```
{% import "_includes/forms/" as forms %}
​
{% set widths = craft.columnwidth.getAllWidths %}

{{ forms.selectField({
    instructions: "Select the width of your column"|t,
    id: 'columnWidth',
    name: 'columnWidth',
    options: widths
}) }}
```

But I'm getting this error:

`Craft\ColumnWidth_WidthsModel and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "optgroup".`

The only post I found was here:

[Displaying a list of fields in a form select](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/4491/displaying-a-list-of-fields-in-a-form-select)

I'm sure I'm missing something and any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few things - you need to add the options to the render function so they are passed into the template. Also, check what I did below for the `$widthsOptions`. Each option needs a label and value key/value pair.

```
public function getInputHtml($name, $value)
{
    // call our service layer to get a current list of widths
    $widths = craft()->columnWidth_widths->getAllWidths();

    // create an array for the widths 
    $widthsOptions = array();

    // populate the $widthsOptions array with $widths
    foreach ($widths as $width )
    {
        $widthsOptions[] = array(
            'label' => $width->name, //this should be whatever you want to display in dropdown
            'value' => $width->name //this should be the value you want passed to the database
        );
    }

    return craft()->templates->render('columnwidth/_fieldtypes/widths', array(
        'name'      => $name,
        'values'    => $value,
        'options'   => $widthsOptions
    ));
}
```

Your field type template should be something like this:

```
{% import "_includes/forms/" as forms %}
​
{{ forms.selectField({
    instructions: "Select the width of your column"|t,
    id: 'columnWidth',
    name: 'columnWidth',
    options: options,
    value: values
}) }}
```

Comment: what would cause the selected value to not save? on save the value keeps reverting back to the first value.

Comment: Is the value saving correctly in the database and just not showing up as the selected item, or is it not saving at all?

Comment: It's saving, so at least there's that :)

Comment: Just updated the answer - you need to have `value: values` in the selectField macro options so it knows which value is currently saved in the database.

Comment: Nice, really wish there was some documentation on this besides rummaging around in the `forms` :)

Comment: any ideas on getting it to display in my templates now? :) that's my final piece! new question perhaps?

Comment: What are you trying to display? Since this is a fieldtype, all you need to is add it to a section/entry type just as you would a normal field. You can then call it in your templates: `{{entry.yourFieldHandle}}`